# UIPanGestureRecognizer on multiple view - Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, uipangesturerecognizer

I have 2 imageviews that I want to be able to move. This is my code:

```
panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureRecognizerMethod:)];

imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
imageview.frame = CGRectMake(390, 100, 80, 16);
imageview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[imageview addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
[self addSubview:imageview];

imageview2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
imageview2.frame = CGRectMake(390, 120, 80, 17);
imageview2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[imageview2 addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
[self imageview2];
```

And in my gestureRecognizer method:

```
- (void)gestureRecognizerMethod:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.view == imageview)
    {
        if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || recognizer.state ==  UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
        {
            CGPoint startPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self];
            imageview.center = startPoint;
        }
    }
    if (recognizer.view == imageview2)
    {
        if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
        {
            CGPoint startPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self];
            imageview2.center = startPoint;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm only able to move one of the view. What is wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

[ResizeImage](https://github.com/bitmantra1/ResizeImage) on github

Comment: The question is about moving the image views, not resizing the images  displayed by the views...

Comment: moving is also available in that. this is the project name only. first download project from above link. don't tell without check it.

Comment: I read the description but not the code. The description does not say it can be used to move the image view. It would be nice if your answer gave more details about how to achieve the goal using your proposed library.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new gesture recognizer for the second image view. You can use the same target and action for both recognisers but you can only attach any one recogniser to a single view.